# Does something similar to "rvim" exist on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, sudo, security, vim, text-editor

I read [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Security#Editing_files_using_sudo) about how to safely edit a file using `sudo`, I do use `sudoedit` most of the time, however I would be interested to know if there is something similar on Ubuntu to `rvim` which is mentioned there.

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20 and as I can't find anything in the repositories with the same or a similar name I was wondering if `rvim` or a similar restrictive text editor exists in Ubuntu?

Comment: Well, according to the `vim` man page, rvim `Can  also  be done with the "-Z" argument.`

Comment: @steeldriver: Oh, please post that as an answer then so that I can accept it!

Comment: There's no separate package for `rvim`, but installing `vim` does install a `/usr/bin/rvim` executable. Check your dir. I have it on my system. (But it doesn't show up in the list of installed files for vim, which I can't explain.) You can call it with `rvim` as you would expect. According to the man file, the `-Z works like the executable [that] starts with "r",` so its the functional equivalent of `rvim` but is not literally calling the `rvim` executable.

Comment: @chaskes: Strange! I could have sworn it wasn't finding `rvim` before when just running it like that.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda We've all had things like that happen. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be no independent `rvim` binary, however installing the `vim` package creates a symbolic link using the `update-alternatives` mechanism:

```
Setting up vim (2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/vim.basic to provide /usr/bin/vim (vim) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/vim.basic to provide /usr/bin/vimdiff (vimdiff) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/vim.basic to provide /usr/bin/rvim (rvim) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/vim.basic to provide /usr/bin/rview (rview) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/vim.basic to provide /usr/bin/vi (vi) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/vim.basic to provide /usr/bin/view (view) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/vim.basic to provide /usr/bin/ex (ex) in auto mode
```

Following the link, we find that the link eventually resolves to `vim.basic`

```
$ readlink -f $(which rvim)
/usr/bin/vim.basic
```

Presumably there's some `argv[0]` magic inside `vim.basic` that causes it to run it in restricted mode when invoked as `rvim`.

According to the `vim` manpage you can also use the `-Z` option:

```
rvim rview rgvim rgview
          Like the above, but with restrictions.  It will not be possi‐
          ble to start shell commands, or suspend  Vim.   Can  also  be
          done with the "-Z" argument.
```

Which provides the same functionality in `vim` as `rvim`, but is not literally calling `rvim`.

Comment: Perhaps you should add it to your answer, I just tried running `rvim` with `vim` installed and I'm pretty sure I got it! Seems to be as said [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/813411/does-something-similar-to-rvim-exist-on-ubuntu?noredirect=1#comment1230593_813411).

Comment: I edited your answer with my suggestion, please do edit it though as you wish. I just wanted to quickly get the information in there.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda it appears to be some `update-alternatives` magic